# Get another order after limit

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

Imagine I've a table 'users' with two fields: 'age' and 'name'. I want to retrieve the top ten older users and then I want this list of ten sorted by name.

Is it possible to do it with MySQL?

I've tried this: (doesn't work)

```
SELECT * FROM users order by age, name limit 10
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Hmm I have tried similar query on similar table(I think so) and working fine for me...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use a subselect:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    ORDER BY age DESC
    LIMIT 10
) AS T1
ORDER BY name
```

The inner select finds the 10 rows you want to return, and the outer select puts them in the correct order.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: It's an alias for the derived table. Unfortunately this alias is necessary to appease MySQL even though it is never used :(. Omitting it gives this error: `Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: You don't need an `AS` before it?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Nope, but adding `AS` I guess does make it more clear what it is. Added.

Comment: That is so great. I was believing a subselect is only working as a field. Thank you, you made my day!