# Get last few records put in table in order of ID with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table where I would like to get the last 3 records from in order of when they were added to the database. I have the following:

```
session.query(User).order_by(User.id.desc()).limit(3)
```

This gets the last 3 records from the database however they are in the backwards order has I descend the ID. I would like to have the records in order however using multiple order queries doesn't seem to work.

Is there a workaround or solution? Thanks.

Comment: `reversed(session.query(User).order_by(User.id.desc()).limit(3))` ?

Comment: @Gerrat Just tried that out, got an error stating a query has no len().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any way to do that other than using a subquery to perform the second `order by` you want, to generate SQL as suggested by this answer: [Get another order after limit with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786570/get-another-order-after-limit-with-mysql)

I believe you'll have to do something like this in SQLAlchemy:

```
session.query(session.query(User).order_by(User.id.desc()).limit(3)\
.subquery().alias('sUser')).order_by('sUser.id')
```

This is untested code and I'm pretty sure you'll end up with a series of KeyedTuple objects, not instances of your User class, although there might be a way to fix that.

However, as you're doing this with the ORM, I don't see much of a point in doing that with an SQLAlchemy subquery at the SQL level if you can do it with Python. Something like:

```
reversed(session.query(User).order_by(User.id.desc()).limit(3).all())
```

Or even this, if you want a list and not a reverse iterator:

```
session.query(User).order_by(User.id.desc()).limit(3).all()[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The truth is I have a similar problem but when I saw how you wrote the command I realized what I needed to do and it worked,
then:
First thing thanks
Second thing I think you need to implement the following command:

```
desc3user = User.query.order_by(User.id.desc()).limit(3)
```

Comment: Could you explain in some detail how this command addresses the question? It would improve the answer greatly!